# Como declarar funções em uma array declarada no bloco de uma classe?

Tags: php

Ao mínimo tentei, mas o PHP joga um erro de síntaxe:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)

Resumindo, não posso declarar funções na minha array.

Quando eu crio a minha array `$ast` fora do bloco da classe `PMoon`, funciona. Há alguma outra maneira de declarar essa array contendo funções?

```
<?php

/* ... */

class PMoon {

    /* ... */

    public $ast = array(

        "labelStatement" => function($label) { // o erro começa aqui
        return array(
            "type" => 'LabelStatement',
            "label" => $label
        );
        }

        /* ... */

    );

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a página do [PHP sobre propriedades](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.properties.php), isso acontece porque:

> [...] São definidas usando uma das palavras-chave `public`, `protected`, or
>   `private`, seguidas de uma declaração normal de variável. Esta
>   declaração pode incluir sua inicialização, **porém esta inicialização
>   deve ser um valor constante - isso é, deve ser possível avaliá-lo em
>   tempo de compilação e não deve-se depender de informações de tempo de
>   execução**.

Uma forma de resolver isso é usar o `array` no método [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
class PMoon{
    public $ast = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->ast = array('labelStatement' => 
        create_function('$label', 'return array("type" => "LabelStatement", 
                                                "label" => $label);'
        )); 
    }
}
```

E para usá-la, faça assim:

```
$moon = new PMoon;
$labelFunc = $moon->ast['labelStatement']('Foo bar');

var_dump($labelFunc);

//array(2) {
//  ["type"]=>
//  string(14) "LabelStatement"
//  ["label"]=>
//  string(7) "Foo bar"
//}
```

Ver [demonstração](https://ideone.com/4Z1mUN)